# Can't access User's Role with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User table which has a reference on a Role model. I want a User to have only one Role so I set up a `has_one` association in my `User` model like this:

```rb
has_one :role
```

And this is my `Role` model association:

```rb
belongs_to :user
```

This is what I have in my `schema.rb` for user table:

```rb
# other stuff
t.bigint "role_id"
t.index ["role_id"], name: "index_users_on_role_id"
```

I think I planned out my role system poorly but I am trying to save it. I want to access the user's role by using `user.role` with `user` being an instance of the `User` model.

Why is it when I call `user.role` I get an error saying:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column roles.user_id does not exist) LINE 1: SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = $1 L...`

**UPDATE**
Migration file for creating Role table:

```rb
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, default: ""
      t.boolean :can_delete_any_job, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :can_kick_any_user, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :can_claim_any_application, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :can_create_events, null: false, default: false
      t.boolean :can_create_news_announcement, null: false, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a column named `user_id` on the `roles` table. You can create a new migration to solve this.

```
rails g migration add_missing_columns

# in the migration
add_column :roles, :user_id, :integer
remove_column :users, :role_id

# then in console
rails db:migrate
```

---

Ideally however you would want a join table with something like

```
create_table :roles_users do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :role
end
```

and then

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_users
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles_users
  has_many :users, through: :roles_users
end

class RolesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'user_id' field to roles table. You keep the associations in model as it is and this will fix the issue. This because the model having the belongs_to association will store the foreign key.

Also, I suggest you have the role_id stored in users table as multiple users will have same role. So, this will avoid the duplication of roles in roles table for each user.
So, the Role model will have 'has_one' association and User model will have 'belongs_to' association. The foreign key 'role_id' will go to users table. And, finally keep the roles table as it is now.

Ref help document: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association